# Reference Error JavaScript even with typeof checking in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a block of code as below and I still get a reference error even though I am checking if the variable is not "undefined"

**I have commented-out `pages2` intentionally to check for errors, because in the backend `pages2` is optional. This is for error checking, since later I will going to use redux and read props from there**

```
// const pages2 = ["Help?", "Retailers"];

{typeof pages2 !== "undefined" ? (
          <>
            <Divider
              light="true"
              orientation="vertical"
              variant="middle"
              flexItem
            />
            {pages2.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                className="menu-stack-header-item"
                sx={{ display: "block" }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
```

As you could see I have wrapped my code in an if statement but still I get a reference error for `pages2` variable where I am using the `map` method to iterate through pages.

what could be done in this instances?

btw, for some other reasons `React` only accepts the ternary if statement here and I can't use `if (typeof pages2 !== "undefined"){...}`

it throws an error when I use a conventional if form

**This is the full code from the component**

```
import { Button, Divider, Stack, Box } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";

import "./NavMenu.style.scss";

function NavMenu() {
  const pages = ["Home", "Supermarket", "Offers"];
  // const pages2 = ["Blog", "Contact"];
  // const pages3 = ["Help?", "Retailers"];
  return (
    <Stack
      className="menu-stack-header"
      direction="row"
      justifyContent="space-between"
      // alignItems="center"
      spacing={1}
    >
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
        }}
      >
        {pages.map((page) => (
          <Button
            key={page}
            className="menu-stack-header-item"
            sx={{ display: "block" }}
          >
            {page}
          </Button>
        ))}

        {typeof pages2 !== "undefined" ? (
          <>
            <Divider
              light="true"
              orientation="vertical"
              variant="middle"
              flexItem
            />
            {pages2.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                className="menu-stack-header-item"
                sx={{ display: "block" }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}

        {typeof pages3 !== "undefined" ? (
          <>
            <Divider
              light="true"
              orientation="vertical"
              variant="middle"
              flexItem
            />
            {pages3.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                className="menu-stack-header-item"
                sx={{ display: "block" }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </Box>
    </Stack>
  );
}

export default NavMenu;
```

Comment: what is `pages2` ? post the exact error, may be a screen shot would help ..

Comment: can you please change `typeof  pages2 !== "undefined"` to `page2 && page2.length`.

Comment: `pages2` is the same as `pages4` , I renamed the variable to check what happens if the variable doesn't exist in the backend

Comment: 1st of all. in your component there is no such variables as pages2 and pages3. If we assume that it is just misspelling for here and you defined them correctly, they will never be undefined. They will be arrays. So your condition is not gonna work. You can use array.length > 0, so you don't have an empty array

Comment: I had changed the names for error checking, I want to check what happens if `pages2` is not defined at all to check whether is it as array or not. what is the correct approach to check for undefined variables in JS, I can't find anything that works here, maybe try catch could work but still throws an error

Comment: It does render `false` part of ternary .. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-peoxmc?file=App.tsx e.g.

Comment: @Shayande it is very different if some variable type is not defined and if it has never been declared at all!
var page2;
now page2 is undefined. typeof page2 equals to undefined.
If you dont declare a page2 anywhere and try to use something doesn't exists, of course you will get a reference error

Comment: I'm with KcH it does render false. Also you can check the conditional render for React here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html. Are you using typescript? Does the error appears in compilation or in execution?